# Is it possible to duplicate a label in javafx at runtime?

Tags: java, javafx, label

I'm very new to programming so i need a bit help with this question please.
I want do dublicate the "testLabel" and put it in different positions. Is this possible?

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{
  if(student.getBereich equals ausgewählter Bereich)  
    for (i=0; i<=3; i++){
      try {
        ArrayList<Student> studiList = readJSON();
        for (Student student : studiList) { 
           int j = 115;
           testLabel.setText(student.getVorname()+" "+student.getNachname());
           testLabel.setLayoutX(175);
           testLabel.setLayoutY(j);
           testLabel.setVisible(true);
           java.util.Collections.sort(studiList, Collator.getInstance());
        }
        //i<3 in anz_studenten ändern!!
         for (i=0; i<3; i++){
           for (Student student : studiList) {
            Image img = new Image(student.getBild()); 
            testImage.setImage(img);
            testImage.setLayoutX(15);
            testImage.setLayoutY(30);
            testImage.setFitHeight(190);
            testImage.setFitWidth(160);
            testImage.setVisible(true);
            java.util.Collections.sort(studiList, Collator.getInstance());
         }
         }
        } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: You can create as many `Label`s and add them to the `Scene` as you want, but you cannot add the same node twice to the scene-graph.

Comment: Furthermore you must not modify a collection while you're iterating it. `java.util.Collections.sort(studiList, Collator.getInstance());` should be done prior to the loop.

Comment: Okey, but can i create ,for example, 3 Labels with a Loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add multiple labels here's an example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainNoFXML extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Label label = new Label("Label Number"+i);
            vBox.getChildren().add(label);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped so much :)